# create list of buckets of rows based on the value of N

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with say 11 rows. I want to create a list of column based on the value of N as below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import sys

df = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5]})
df
```

For example:

If N value is given as 2, then I want to create 2 list somewhat like below:

```
list = [[1,1,1,2,2,2,2], [3,3,4,5]]
```

so that each group stays in the same list. It is fine if length of the lists are not same.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure you get `N` groups that are as evenly split as possible you should use `pd.cut`. We use `rank` to ensure that groups are densely labeled, otherwise this will not work properly. This ensures an even splitting of the number of groups to each list +/-1, though will not ensure the lists are nearly the same length.

```
N = 2
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.group.rank(method='dense'), N)).group.agg(list).tolist()
#[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [4, 5]]

N = 3
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.group.rank(method='dense'), N)).group.agg(list).tolist()
#[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 5]]
```